# Java Assemblier Debugging

Tags: java

I am working on my java program, which basically converts one group of strings, and replaces them with a different grouping of strings.

I am having a few issues which I cannot seem to get my head around. I was hoping someone could run the code and try to help find the solution. I am getting a NoSuchElement error, which is confusing me quite a lot.

**EDIT: The `operation=sc.next();' is giving me a NoSuchElementException error.**

The end goal, is once the input file is translated, I would write that to a new file.

The short code is the MIPS code that is to be debugged. Needs to be in a .mas file.

```
     ldc  3000 ; get multiplier                        
     push      ; push one number onto stack            
     ldc  4    ; get multilplicand                     
     m         ; multiply using shift-add in microcode 
     halt
```

Comment: Oops sorry, I will edit that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `operand` you have

```
    //get operand
    if(sc.hasNext()){
        operand=sc.next();
    }
```

which is the correct approach

For `operation`, however, you have just

```
    //get operation
    if(line.contains(":")){//line has label
        sc.next();//skip label
        operation=sc.next();
    }
```

So you cannot guarantee that there will be another token available.

Comment: This could probably be it as well

Comment: Ah ok, I will add in something to fix that issue and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

From the Java API:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html

and

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()

You are running out of elements for Scanner to read, and it throws an exception. You will either need to use a different method to read input, or handle the exception (although you might have to handle them even with a different class).

Comment: Ok, I am feeling a little stuck then. How would I move forward from here, as I don't think I know another way to fix this.

Comment: Well the easiest way could be to just wrap the lines of code where you use sc.next in a try catch block. So something like:

try {
/*Insert scanner code here*/
}
catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
/*we finished reading from the input*/
}

Answer (score 0):

```
//get operation
if(line.contains(":")){//line has label
    sc.next();//skip label
    operation=sc.next();
}
else if(sc.hasNext)){
    operation=sc.next();
}
else operation = "";
```

That fixed it fine, which was what I was looking for.